# Why is my password validation not working Java?

Tags: java, swing, jpasswordfield

I have a password field in my login screen. For some reason when i type in the correct password which is **"u123"** it gives me the incorrect password error message even though it is correct. Why is it doing this.

The code i have below:

```
btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            char[] userInput = passwordField.getPassword();
            char[] correctPassword = { 'u', '1', '2', '3'};

            if (userInput.equals(correctPassword)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginScreen.this,
                    "Success! You typed the right password.");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginScreen.this,
                    "Invalid password. Try again.",
                    "Error Message",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    });
```

I know this may not be the best way of doing the password check but I'm just a beginner and just trying to get some practice.

Comment: Why don't you use strings instead of character arrays?

Comment: @Thomas Strings for passwords are [bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords?rq=1).

Comment: If you use `char []`, can you try using `Arrays.equals`? There is an example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html)

Comment: @user982467 sure it can be. But it shouldn't be. See [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has :

```
char[] userInput = passwordField.getPassword();
char[] correctPassword = { 'u', '1', '2', '3'};
```

It's two different arrays of characters.

So this test returns false :

```
 if (userInput.equals(correctPassword))
```

Instead, try to use the [Arrays.equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(char[],%20char[])) method

```
 if (Arrays.equals(userInput, correctPassword)) { ... }
```

Comment: I tried that and i get error saying Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method equals(Object) from the type Object

Comment: Ok it works now. I changed it to `if (Arrays.equals(userInput, correctPassword))` . Thx

Comment: @Prim indeed you meant `if (Arrays.equals(userInput, correctPassword))`. `Arrays.equals(userInput.equals(correctPassword))` makes no sense

Comment: Yep, true. My bad. it's fixed.